# Mouseover events for Firefox Driver / Selenium Webdriver on Mac OSX doesn't work

Tags: firefox, selenium, webdriver

After searching everywhere, I cannot seem to find a solution for getting mouseover events to work on with Firefox 16.0.2 and Selenium 2.28 on Mac OSX (I believe this is supposedly a problem specific to Mac OSX but this code should work on a Windows machine). I have the following which hovers over objectOnScreen which should reveal somethingElseOnScreen:

```
//set enable native events is suggested by another post to make these native events work
FirefoxProfile prof = new FirefoxProfile(); 
prof.setEnableNativeEvents(true); 
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(prof);

// Hover over objectOnScreen which should reveal somethingElseOnScreen
Action builder;
Actions hover = new Actions(driver);
WebElement objectOnScreen = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//..."))
hover.moveToElement(objectOnScreen);
builder = hover.build();
builder.perform();

// Click something new that should appear on screen
By somethingElseOnScreen = By.xpath("//...");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5L);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(somethingElseOnScreen));
driver.findElement(somethingElseOnScreen).click();
```

This code works in Chrome but not in Firefox. In Firefox, somethingElseOnScreen never appears (I get a NoSuchElementException for the wait.until... line), and when I watch the browser I never see the hover working.

I've also tried these 2 things but neither fixes the issue:

- constructing the builder actions with both the hover and click actions
- using an EventFiringMouse and hovering over that point on the screen but that also doesn't work on Firefox (but is fine on Chrome).

Does anyone have a workaround for this issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My workaround was to manually change the css `display` property of the element to `inline` (or `block` - depending on your HTML code) that is hidden and should appear on "mouseover" (or call the JavaScript that adds the needed element on the same even - depending on your HTML code).

I can tell you specifically what code you can write, if you can tell me 3 things:

1. what language you are using for Selenium
2. HTML/css properties of element before `mouseover`
3. HTML/css properties of element after `mouseover`

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm using Selenium with Java. As for #2 and #3, we're using the css :hover psuedoclass. After some quick searching, it didn't seem like there was a way to trigger that with Javascript so I'm afraid there might not be a way to manually trigger this hover within Selenium?

Comment: @leslieChong, yes, there is no way to trigger `:hover`, however `:hover` itself triggers something else. (like change the display value) :) That's why I asked for the HTML code of *before* and *after* :)

Comment: Ah, thanks Alex. The hover seems to trigger and div that contains the overlay to change from display:none to display:block. I will try manipulating the CSS is my script. Thanks!